# JpGraph graphics don't appear - (broken image)

Tags: php, jpgraph

I need to install JpGraph to display graphs on my web site.

I unzipped the compressed files, then put them my www folder (of wamp), and tried to access the `testsuit.php` page: `jpgraph-3.5.0b1/src/Examples/testsuit.php`

But the result was:

[image]

GD lib is activated... I don't understand the problem. Only 5-6 graph work on the example page...

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Enter full URL to broken images in your browser directly and see if you won't see any notice or error message. Because if for any reason your php script spits such messages then it become part of image hence broken, not-displayable image

Comment: The problem is here : 
"Warning: require_once(jpgraph/jpgraph.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\up\jpgraph-3.5.0b1\src\Examples\accbarex1.php on line 3"
The file "jpgraph" in the Examples folder just contain "../"
and in the src directory, jpgraph.php is present.
(Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: In cases where the graphic work the include is "../jpgraph.php" and not "jpgraph/jpgraph.php". why wamp does not interprete file jpgraph ?
(Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: I have the same problem, even screenshot is the same. Running jpgraph on localsite with xampp

Answer (score 0):

I had same problemm, I just copy all files from src directory (of course just files, not the directories) in to "Examples" directory, the I created a directory in the "Examples" directory and I named it jpgraph, then I copy all files and directories from "src" directory (except the Examples directories of course) in to that jpgraph directory.

And ready!

Everything worked!!!!